# How do I track plugin dependencies in maven2?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am trying to locate an evil plugin that includes a stoneage version of a certain jar file. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

also, mvn -X will spit out all kinds of info, i believe it includes dependency versions.

Comment: you can see some outputs in target/ folder when using `-X` like details on compiler, surfire, etc... (see *tmp files too)

Answer (score 21):

`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` gives a list of dependencies for each plugin

Comment: NB that (for me) if I have some local dependencies specified that override a parent, `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` still prints out the parent version in error (but the specified ones are used correctly).  Be warned.

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:resolve-plugins (default-cli) on project xxx: Nested: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-project-info-reports-plugin:jar:3.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced :(

Answer (score -3):

`mvn dependency:tree` - shows you a tree of all dependencies including transitive dependencies

Comment: Note: This only displays project dependencies, not plugin dependencies.

Comment: @AlexMiller Of course, but you can always create a separate pom just for this purpose, and in that pom you specify the plugin artifactId, groupId and version in the dependencies section (not in the plugins section). Then `mvn dependency:tree` will work and will not re-download anything.