# How can you display the Maven dependency tree for the *plugins* in your project?

Tags: java, plugins, maven

A common Maven debugging technique is to use [mvn dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to view the graph of project dependencies.

However, this list shows the project dependencies, not the plugin dependency tree for each plugin.  Is there some way to do this from a project?

Comment: Have you tried to run mvn -X ...

Comment: Yes, and that is helpful for certain problems but not what I'm asking for.

Comment: It contains the dependencies of a plugin otherwise there is not such thing available.

Comment: @khmarbaise is correct. The dependency tree of a plugin is available in Maven's debugging output. I don't know of another way to get it, either. (If you turn this into an answer, I'll upvote it.)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/312767/32453

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate pom for the purpose, where the plugin is specified as a project dependency? Then `mvn dependency:tree` should work.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3518674 [Maven Versions Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-plugin-updates-mojo.html) `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The output via mvn -X will printout the information indirectly. Currently there is no other option to get the dependencies of a Maven-Plugin.

**Update**
You can use the following command to get a list of plugin dependencies ([resolve-plugin goal](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-plugins-mojo.html) from dependencies plugin):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:resolve-plugins
```

The shorter version is (and it is a bad habit to specify plugin versions)

```
mvn dependency:resolve-plugins
```

Comment: resolve-plugins doesn't just output the dependency tree... it seems to re-download all of the packages. Not ideal.

Comment: The plugin doesn't respect overriding plugin dependencies in pom.xml (tag `<build><plugins><plugin><dependencies><dependency>`)

Comment: to use of last plugin version : mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:resolve-plugins

Comment: By default maven loads dependency plugin version 2.something. Personally I managed to get better results when using 3.x version.

Comment: It seems to resolve direct dependencies only, not transitive.

Comment: @agad To get transitive dependencies, I just added the plugin as project dependency and rerun the command.

Answer (score -12):

If you are using any IDE like IDEA IntelliJ or Eclipse:

- You can add this below plugin in your pom.xml
- Once done, On the Maven window (on the right of IDE), you will find a new plugin called as
  Dependencies
- Expand that and you will see the dependency:tree goal, double click
  on it and run it, you should see the full dependency tree

Plugin to be added in POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This shows the dependency tree for the project, but to see the plugin dependencies, we need to use `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins` as per khmarbaise answer.