# Where should I place my java test resources if they're relatively large (over 100MB)?

Tags: java, maven, testing, resources, structure

I'm working on a project with a maven structure and I want to begin doing some extended tests, but I'll need to a large amount of resources do to so. Any recommendations where I should place these resources? Should they go into 'src/main/test/resources' or be pulled from a different repo or something else?

Comment: Well, would there be an issue if you stick them in src/main/test/resources? Seems to me like you're asking about a problem that does not even exist yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recapping your question**

> Any recommendations where I should place these resources? [...]
>
> I'm aware that I can place them in 'src/main/test/resources' [...]
>
> I'm thinking more of resources for integration tests. Developers won't necessarily want to pull a 100's of megs of resources from version control for tests they likely won't run.

**Answer**

You might change to a **multi-module project** layout, something like:

```
      multi-module project
              |
              |
          +---+-----------------+ 
          |                     |
source and unit test    integration test
         prj                   prj
```

then your developers could pull only `source and unit test prj`.

Clearly integration test prj should have a compile scoped dependency on `source and unit test prj`.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Solves the problem of having to download integration tests in developers primary work module and gives the option to separately download it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Maven has an answer for you...

If you include the resources inside the 'src/main/test/resources' (that's correct)...

Remember that running an install in the final jar the tests will be excluded, and yes! The resources are excluded too...

Moreover you could skipping tests (also the compilation) to improve compilation performance...
(more info at: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)

I hope this helps you...

UPDATE:

also give a look at "[How can you display the Maven dependency tree for the *plugins* in your project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074590/how-can-you-display-the-maven-dependency-tree-for-the-plugins-in-your-project)"

Comment: Yeah I'm aware that I can place them in 'src/main/test/resources' and in fact I use that directory for resources that unit tests use. However, I'm thinking more of resources for integration tests. Developers won't necessarily want to pull a 100's of megs of resources from version control for tests they likely won't run.

Answer (score 0):

We should think about the reasons for excluding resources from the environment of the developer. I just answer your question telling the common practice of handling situations like yours by Maven...

If as you say it is actually a problem for you, it may be an idea, for example, to separate all the tests and resources inside another moduel...including that in your parent pom...
Or maybe to define a profile (integration test) which will contains largely of test resources, and a profile (Developing test) that will only lead tests useful to the individual developer ...

I personally think that unless there are special reasons (critical), beyond simply the amount of mega occupying test, you can safely proceed with all the resources in the test package...

Answer (score -1):

You should run this kind of large integration tests on a CI server, not on developer machines.

It's good practice to run long-running integration tests on a different machine to reduce the dev-test cycle time. You wouldn't want to run that in your normal builds anyway, make a profile and run it on CI.

Comment: Does not seem to be answering his question at all.

Comment: Hehe, if I get a downvote for promoting good practices when somebody is trying to do something that is affecting the speed and quality of the development cycle then so be it!