# Find Dependency For a plugin in Maven

Tags: maven

Is there a command or way where we can find the dependencies for a plugin in maven?

Say I have a plugin in my *pom.xml*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Now how do I know what are the dependencies for this plugin? Can we see them visually? How do I list out the dependencies for plugin?

Is this the command: `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you display the Maven dependency tree for the \*plugins\* in your project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074590/how-can-you-display-the-maven-dependency-tree-for-the-plugins-in-your-project)

Comment: What is the purpose of seeing them? Some problems with a plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise . Yes problems with a plugin. And also to check whether the dependency jar exists or not.