# Is there a Maven plugin that shows the dependency tree of a plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

Is there an easier way to get the dependency tree of a Maven plugin, other than to checkout its sources and run a `mvn dependency:tree` against them?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html

Comment: @IndraUprade: This is not what I need. This is a flat representation of the current `pom.xml`'s dependencies.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074590/how-can-you-display-the-maven-dependency-tree-for-the-plugins-in-your-project. There is no real built-in ways I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking out the concerned plugin' sources, you can still add it as a dependency of your project and then check its dependency tree as any other maven dependency.

A maven plugin is a `jar` file afterall and could be added as any other maven dependency (not really meaningful, unless in the context of maven plugin development).

For instance, we could had the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.10) as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the `scope` for purity, even though you would probably remove the dependency from your project after the required checks.

Now you can run on this project `dependency:tree` and check the dependencies of this plugin, narrowing down its output via the [`includes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes) property is required.

Comment: A neat hack! Although... if you do it this way, you should also better use `-Dverbose=true` (because some of the project's dependencies my cause the dependencies of the plugin to be replaced in the dependency tree). Not the most elegant solution, but I suppose it will do the trick.

Comment: Also, in my example I should have used a different plugin as dependency: here you are using the dependency plugin to check dependencies of the dependency plugin, this could break the Internet

Answer (score 1):

This is not the exact thing you want but little closer to that, at least it will analyze the dependencies and list out all the warnings upfront.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Dependency-Analyzer</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>analyze-only</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```