# How to find the dependencies of a maven plugin goal

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to find out where the dependencies are coming from for a particular plugin goal. I know the dependencies exist because Maven downloaded them when I ran the goal for the first time. And they're not (directly) dependencies of my project, because I ran `mvn clean install` first, and these dependencies weren't downloaded then.

In this specific case, I'm trying to figure out what the dependencies are when I run `mvn sonar:sonar`, but I expect the answer will be general purpose. For instance, even though I've built this project a number of times, when I ran that goal Maven downloaded a bunch of new jars like maven-antrun-plugin.

Here are things I've tried:

- `mvn dependency:tree` shows the dependencies for the project, but not for the plugin goal (it doesn't include anything related to SonarQube in the list).
- `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom -Dverbose=true` also doesn't include anything related to SonarQube.
- `mvn -X sonar:sonar` prints out what looks like a dependency graph, but it's missing the jars that Maven downloaded the first time I ran the `sonar:sonar` goal.
- `mvn -X dependency:resolve-plugins` seems to be meant to download the dependencies of plugins, but does not capture the `sonar:sonar` dependencies. If I clear out my Maven cache, run `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`, and then run `mvn sonar:sonar`, Maven has to download jars.

Comment: There two thing. Sonar plugin itself loads separately something down from sonar server... and the real maven plugin...

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7079876/294657) what you're looking for?

Comment: Another option is to find the POM of the plugin project. Either on the internet or by using IDE navigation features (e.g. Ctrl + Clicking on the plugin declaration in your project's POM). Don't know if there is a way just for an invidigual goal, though.

Comment: @kaqqao I forgot to include that in the "things I've tried". I've added it now.

Comment: @RetoHöhener I tried doing that using mvnrepository.com, but it became clear that trying to trace the tree manually is very time consuming.

Comment: You probably have to look at the sources of the sonar plugin. May I ask why are trying to find these dependencies? Are you trying to build some kind of offline system? Or are you looking for a specific dependency?

Answer (score 2):

Use your IDE to navigate to the POM of the plugin project and then look at the dependency tree.

Or do this manually by copying the plugin POM to your file system and running `mvn dependency:tree`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies downloaded by maven are generally stored locally on the pc at the address **C:\Users\yourUser/.m2** this regardless of your projects and so that you do not have to reload dependencies that you are already using in other projects.

I hope I have understood your question and that my answer is useful to you, greetings.

Comment: I'm looking for how to determine what all the dependencies of a plugin are, similar to what `mvn dependency:tree` does for a project

Comment: This is just for Windows and there's something missing. More general and complete it's `${user.home}/.m2/repository` as default and can be re-defined in [`settings.xml`](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).