# How to get maven dependency tree programmatically

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-tree

want to print maven dependency tree (all the dependencies including transitive dependencies) programmatically by just reading pom.xml file without connecting to remote repository.

Comment: Without reading the (remote) repository it is not possible.

Comment: If I use remote repository, nothing is printing on console. If anyone knows, how to do it connecting to remote repository, please share.

Comment: Please show your code ? Why not using Maven itself or `maven-dependency-plugin:tree` ? etc. ?

Comment: It might be worth to take a look here: https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/tree/master/maven-resolver-demos/maven-resolver-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/resolver/examples

Comment: want to print dependency tree at runtime using java code.

Comment: MavenXpp3Reader mavenReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model;
        File pomFile = new File("/pom.xml");
        model = mavenReader.read(new FileReader(pomFile));
        MavenProject project=new MavenProject(model);

Comment: DefaultArtifact pomArtifact = new DefaultArtifact(project.getId());
        RepositorySystem repoSystem = Booter.newRepositorySystem( Booter.selectFactory( args ) );
        RepositorySystemSession repoSession = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( repoSystem ); // TODO
       List<RemoteRepository> remoteRepos = project.getRemoteProjectRepositories();
        List<Dependency> ret = new ArrayList<Dependency>();
        Dependency dependency = new Dependency(pomArtifact, "compile");

Comment: At runtime? Why ? At runtime you don't have access to your repositories or maybe not to your pom file at all etc. ?

Comment: CollectRequest collectRequest = new CollectRequest();
        collectRequest.setRoot(dependency);
        collectRequest.setRepositories(remoteRepos);
        DependencyNode node = repoSystem.collectDependencies(repoSession, collectRequest).getRoot();
        DependencyRequest projectDependencyRequest = new DependencyRequest(node, null);
        repoSystem.resolveDependencies(repoSession, projectDependencyRequest);
        PreorderNodeListGenerator nlg = new PreorderNodeListGenerator();
        node.accept(nlg);

Comment: ret.addAll(nlg.getDependencies(true));
        for(Dependency dep:ret){
            System.out.println(dep.getArtifact());
        }

Comment: The MavenXpp3 reader will only give the plain pom content...nothing resolved...

Comment: Take a deep look into Maven Resolver (see answer or in comment).

Comment: github.com/apache/maven-resolver/tree/master/… 
I have tried it and it is working for maven dependency, but when I want to use custom group id, artifact id and version it is not giving the output.

Comment: how can we connect to our own repo instead of https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/?

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible, sorry. Also, have you checked the answer and comments here? [How can you display the Maven dependency tree for the *plugins* in your project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074590/how-can-you-display-the-maven-dependency-tree-for-the-plugins-in-your-project)

Comment: want to print dependency tree using java code not using maven command.

Comment: Then you're going to have to re-implement the Maven dependency analyser yourself. I believe this to be a suboptimal choice.

Comment: In Maven project, inside external libraries, every jar has pom.properties file, Is it possible to read values from each and every jar's pom.properties in java code?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to take a look at the maven resolver project which has some example code which might be sufficient as a starting point:

https://github.com/apache/maven-resolver/tree/master/maven-resolver-demos/maven-resolver-demo-snippets/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/resolver/examples

Comment: how can we connect to our own repo instead of repo.maven.apache.org/maven2? –

Comment: Read the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `ProcessBuilder` to retrieve the result of maven's `dependency:tree` command.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "mvn -f \"C:\\myprojectpath\"", "dependency:tree");

    try {

        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Read more [here](https://mkyong.com/java/java-processbuilder-examples/).